# Storing values without an array or vector C++

Tags: c++, pointers, mergesort

I'm doing a project in order to familiarize myself using pointers. I want to enter a set of values, using only pointers to merge sort them and print them out. I don't want to use arrays or vectors for this project...

**MY QUESTION:**
Is there a way to keep track of multiple values entered by a user with out arrays or vectors?

Comment: Only pointers sorry =p that's the challenge

Comment: Are you going to create hundreds of unique variable identifiers to hold each pointer?  What's wrong with using an array to hold pointers to objects, for example?

Comment: Then clarify your question. There is a multitude of data structures out there.

Comment: Well, you'll either need a variable for each value, or you'll need a data structure like an array or list.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way to reference values using pointers and this projects helping me familiarize myself with pointers

Comment: So the point is not to use an _existing_ data structure? In that case Damien's suggestion of a linked list is probably the right exercise for you.

Comment: Doing a merge-sort on a datastructure that doesn't feature random-access (this includes linked lists) is non-trivial.

Comment: @user3319775 building a Linked list class would certainly familiarize you with pointers, and you would need to work with those pointers for sorting.

Comment: IMHO, this is not a very practical use of pointers.  Therefore the exercise might do you more harm than good.  Are pointers really that hard to understand that you need to assign yourself such an arduous task?  Strange.

Answer (score 5):

The most common data structure that is not stored as an array is a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). A linked list uses pointers to 'link' together a 'list' of objects.

Comment: I ended up using num = new float[values]; Its not an array but a pointer with x amount of values to point to

Comment: @user3319775: `new float[values]` **is** an array. It lives on the heap instead of on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You may use concept of linked list.
You may code it as follows

```
struct node 
{
  int n;
  struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;
```

then for inserting a number, allocate memory dynamically to a node variable and attach it to start node as follows.

```
struct node *neww=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
neww->n=Number to insert;
neww->next=NULL;
start=neww;
```

Comment: Why use `malloc` instead of `new` ?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused with C. You can use new operator in C++.